# HTML form validation for number

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I  want to enter only **4 digits** between `0001` to `9999` then how to I validate?

I used `[0-9]{4}` but it contains `0000` also.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a simple regex for a range between `0001` and `9999`.

`^(0{3}[1-9]|0{2}[1-9]\d|0[1-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d{3})$`

My solution is to split expression for each degree.

```
0{3}[1-9]   = 0001 - 0009
0{2}[1-9]\d = 0010 - 0099
0[1-9]\d{2} = 0100 - 0999
[1-9]\d{3}  = 1000 - 9999
```

You can play with this regex online https://regex101.com/r/TjzoEh/1

Use `pattern` attribute of text input to validate your regex.

```
<input type="text" pattern="^(0{3}[1-9]|0{2}[1-9]\d|0[1-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d{3})$" title="Four digits code">
```

Inspired by https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 0):

for set your length, you must use maxlength attribute like this:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4"/>
```

and for check number type, you can use **Regular Expressions** or **Number.isInteger()** method.

For first way, you can use this pattern and find any non-digit in your input

```js
// Find a non-digit character
let reg = /\D/;
```

and finally, use it:

```js
reg.test({{your value}})
```

For second way, you have to use **eval()** method in the **Number.isInteger()** method, for example:

```js
Number.isInteger(eval({{ your value }}))
```

NOTE: if you use **type="number"** attribute in input, use don't have to use regex or any js methods.